# How to enable table overflow scroll? (especially order list table)

Tags: css, admin-css, screen-layout

[image: Not able to scroll]

Above in image the order list table not able to scroll horizontally and also breaking the words . I want to make scroll . Help me how to do this ?

Comment: try to add this style to the table : `table-layout : initial;`

Comment: May you elaborate more? where is this coming from? A custom code? What did you do to try to fix it?

Comment: Disable one of the columns using screen options on top. This should sort out width of the column.